# Is is an anti-pattern to inject DI container to (almost) each class?

Tags: dependency-injection

Lately I find myself not caring too much defining dependencies for a class and passing them in the constructor, but I just always pass the DI container and keep it in a private attribute. This way my class won't have very well-defined dependencies, I get everything from the container when I need it.

Somehow I have bad feelings about this solution though (apart from the overhead caused by accessing the container), but I can't really think of too much disadvantages. Maybe having loose definition of dependencies can decrease portability of a class, or I get surprises when refactoring...?

What do you think about this?

Comment: Injecting the container into a class is just a form of the Service Locator anti-pattern and is (almost) as bad as calling a static Service Locator intance.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931321/why-injecting-whole-service-container-to-another-service-is-almost-always-a-ba

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Absolutely wrong.  Don't put the DI container in the objects; they need not know or care that they're being injected.  This doesn't square with "don't call us; we'll call you."

It's the other way 'round: the overall app knows about the DI engine, but then it gets the beans it needs from it.

I suppose you might argue that annotations change the relationship some, because now the beans *do* know something about the fact that they're wired together.  But when configuration was externalized into XML, it was true that beans were ignorant of DI.

Answer (score 3):

This is an anti-pattern and I dare to bet that you are not writing tests yet for your code which is really bad.

When you start writing tests you will find that you are writing un-testable code, and you are:

- Using the Service Locator anti-pattern
- You are violating the Law of Demeter
- You are not following the Single Responsibility Principle
- You are hiding your object real dependencies (Not using the Dependency-Injection pattern)
- You do not have a real separation between the two big piles of object in any application:

  - Business objects: Responsibility is business logic, domain abstractions
  - Wiring and building objects: Responsibility is to build object graphs

The day you want to write unit-tests for your components you will regret this decision and you will have either refactor your code or write integration tests instead of simple unit-tests (creating a test container and inject mocks to this container).

My advise is read this guide to write testable code: (this is the guide used by the guys working hard in Google)

http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/

if you prefer, start with these videos from Misko Hevery about the psychology of testing and clean code talks:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w&feature=player_embedded

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0&feature=player_embedded

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI&feature=player_embedded

Comment: I think you are dramatizing the situation a bit here. I'm indeed writing unit tests to my classes and I don't see how defining fixtures in my DI container instead of passing them directly makes things any complicated. Nor I agree with your point about SRP, and only partly what you say about the law of demeter (it's a container). You imply here too many things.