# symfony An error has occurred: Notice: Undefined property: ::$container

Tags: php, database, symfony, sockets, websocket

I working on a web socket app using ratchet and symfony 2.8 to connect to database and changing value in a certain column if someone connect to the server but I get error in this line

```
    $sql = $this->container->get('database_connection');
```

the full error message

An error has occurred: Notice: Undefined property: check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat::$container

my injection in the services.yml code

```
services:
     database_connection:
         class: check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat
         arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

my Chat.php code

```
<?php
namespace check\roomsBundle\Sockets;
use tuto\testBundle\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface  {


    protected $clients;
    //protected $db;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";

        $sql = $this->container->get('database_connection');
        $users = $sql->query("UPDATE user SET ONoff= '1' WHERE UserId='2'");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so there's a few things that you'll need to fix in order to solve your problem.

```
services:
     database_connection:
         class: check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat
         arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

What this is doing is when it calls the constructor it's going to pass in the service container, however using the constructor to pass in your container isn't favorable, but rather instead you should implement the `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface` interface and then implement the method `setContainer` and optional a `getContainer` method.

```
/**
 * @param ContainerInterface|NULL $container
 */
public function setContainer(
    ContainerInterface $container = NULL
)
{
    $this->container = $container;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return ContainerInterface
 */
protected function getContainer()
{
    return $this->container;
}
```

And then after that update your service to call this method when initializing it.

```
services:
     chat_service: # renamed because this is your chat service, not your database connection
         class: check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat
         calls:
             - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

Comment: i get this error inerAwareInterface::setContainer() cannot contain body in

Comment: Did you want to complete the error message you get?

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Interface function Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface::setContainer() cannot contain body in /opt/lampp/htdocs/x/1/sym/thesym/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareInterface.php on line 24

Comment: the error on this line public function setContainer(
    ContainerInterface $container = NULL
)

Comment: Its seems as though you've modified this file. `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareInterface.php`, you should *never* modify anything in the `vendor` folder. The changes I've provided were mean't to be done in the chat.php file, or some other class inherited by it, using the `extends` keyword.

Comment: i get this error massage for this line $sql = $this->container->get('database_connection');

i tried to changes it to $sql = $this->get('database_connection');
but i still get the same error

Comment: I'll repeat again. You've changed the above mentioned file, you shouldn't be doing that. You need to revert that file to it's previous state. Assuming you're using composer just delete the entire `vendor` folder and run `composer install` again.

Answer (score 1):

Your service is fine you just need little changes in your chat.php class

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface  {

protected $clients;
private $container;
//protected $db;
public function __construct(Container $container) {
    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

Now u can use `$this->container`

> Updated

Try to inject entity manager

```
services:
  database_connection:
    class: check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat
    arguments: 
        - @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
```

in chat.php do like this

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface  {

   protected $clients;
   protected $em;
   public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
       $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
       $this->em = $em;
   }
$this->em->getRepository('yorrepo')->updateFuntion();
```

Now try to call from some repo to update

Comment: i get this error   [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                      
  Type error: Argument 1 passed to check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat::__construc  
  t() must implement interface  rInterface, none given, called in

Answer (score -1):

Injecting the service container is generally considered as a [bad idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931321/in-symfony2-why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-inject-the-service-container-rather-than-i)

you should consider to inject `database_connection` service .

There are few ways to do that. Have a look at [Types of Injection.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html)

```
services:
     chat_service:
         class: check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat
         arguments: ["@database_connection"]
```

your class

```
protected $connection;

public function __construct($connection) {
    $this->connection = $connection;
}
```

Even if you want to go ahead with injecting the service container, the above link has relavent documentation that will help you to solve the issue you are facing.

Comment: added exaple code, requesting the user who downvoted to comment on why they did so.

Comment: thank you for answer i get this error when i try your code   [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException]  
  Circular reference detected for service "database_connection", path: "datab          
  ase_connection -> database_connection".

Comment: In the example from the answer, the service id should be something different than `database_connection`. You could also change the id of the injected service. However, as the class name is something about a chat, the service should rather not be named like something related to a database connection.

Comment: @xabbuh , thanks xabbbuh.totally missed to catch the circular reference error when I posted the the anser..  Un-related to your comment : my answer was downvoted before I added the code example, I thought it was downvoted due to non presence of an example.

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                    
  Warning: Missing argument 1 for check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat::__construct  
  (), called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/x/1/sym/thesym/src/check/roomsBun  
  dle/Command/SocketCommand.php on line 41 and defined