# How to get Tempating or Container in custom Service?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I have custom Service and I would like to use it in Twig templates.
In Symfony < 3 I can do:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
//...
public function __construct(Container $container) 
{
    $this->container = $container;
}

public function getView()
{
    $this->container->get('templating')->render('default/view.html.twig');
}
```

But in Symfony 3.3 I have error:

> Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Service\ViewService": argument
>   "$container" of method "__construct()" references class
>   "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container" but no such service
>   exists. Try changing the type-hint to one of its parents: interface
>   "Psr\Container\ContainerInterface", or interface
>   "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [not good idea to inject whole container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26144509). Better is to inject single dependencies:

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;

class MyService
{
    private $templating;
    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function getView()
    {
        $this->templating->render('default/view.html.twig');
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how did you know what interface to use? Where can I check it? If I run "bin/console debug:container" then I have: 'templating                                                                                                              alias for "templating.engine.twig" '  . So why and how EngineInterface?

Comment: @roggy using `bin/console debug:container templating` gives you [hint of autowiring types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fkeN.png).