# Symfony 4 - accessing parameters inside a Controller

Tags: symfony, parameters, symfony4

I'm trying to get some parameters defined in the `services.yaml` into one of my controllers, but I can't seem to find anything that works.

The idea is that I want to have a common string inside all of my controllers that defines the prefix of all the routes inside my application, for example `/api/v1/`.

I'm trying to store that string inside the `services.yaml` file as it seems the appropriate place to do it.

Also, I would like to use the contents of these parameters inside the method annotation...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Symfony 4.1 you will be able to [wire container parameters automatically](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-getting-container-parameters-as-a-service).

For now you have to explicitly tell the dependency injection component how to wire such property. You can create a service for that to have it autowired everywhere you want:

```
namespace App\Provider;

final class DefaultEndpointProvider
{
    private $url;

    public function __construct(string $url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }
}
```

service definition:

```
# todo: replace with parameter bind in Sf4.1
App\Provider\DefaultEndpointProvider:
  arguments:
    $url: '%common_url_parameter%'
```

then you can simply require that service as a dependency in your controllers / services etc.

Comment: and is this available as well on Route annotations?

Comment: It [should](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/service_container_parameters.html). Haven't you tried yet?

Comment: @Route("/user/list/", name="user-list"), how can I call the method inside this annotation? I have no idea

Comment: Don't call a method, try with the parameter `@Route("%common_url_parameter%/user/list/"...`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to inject the parameter you can use this:

```
$this->getParameter('your.parameter');
```

service.yaml

```
parameters:
    your.parameter: /api/v1/
```

Comment: Just mind that accessing anything via a container is an antipattern.

Comment: @Vyctorya how can I inject the parameter?

Comment: look at emix answer :)

Comment: it is and anti pattern, this means you should not use it if you can. if there is no other option. the i would use the $this->getParameter()

Comment: @emix about the anti-pattern comment you made, can you please point us your source? Or give us some clarification of why is it so?

Comment: @emix nevermind. The answer provided by Dan Blows at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931321/in-symfony2-why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-inject-the-service-container-rather-than-i says it all.

Comment: This is violation of the Law of Demeter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that accessing parameters from a service is the better choice. I will suggest you rather to define your parameter in the "bind" section of service.yaml file like this

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

        # Bind all arguments requested by multiple services (auto-wiring)
        bind:
            $yourParameter: '%your.parameter%'
```

Put a parameter in this bind section allows you to inject it like a service in all other services (including controllers).

Then in your controllers and all other services, you could do something like this:

```
class RandomController extends Controller
{
    private $yourParameter;

    public function __construct(string $yourParameter)
    {
        $this->yourParameter = $yourParameter;
    }
    ...
```

I answered your question about injecting parameters. Now if you want to use it in your route annotation, I would test something like this.

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/{apiVersion}/the/rest/of/your/route", name="route_name", defaults={"apiVersion"="%yourParameter%"})
 */
public function yourAction()
{}
```

I didn't test this last solution. Don't know if it still work with symfony 4. If not maybe try to put %$yourParameter% (with a '$'). Tell me about that.

Edit:

Or even better for you situation (I assume that you are using the annotation routing): I guess your parameter is important only for the /api/ part of your application. Then you can define in your config/routes/annotations.yaml file all your controller concerned by your api. I suggest something like this.

```
controllers:
    path: /api/{apiVersion}
    resource: ../../src/Controller/Api
    type: annotation
    defaults:
        apiVersion : '%your.parameter%'
    # And maybe add also requirements like this
    requirements:
        apiVersion: 'v0|v1|v2'
```

Where all your api controllers are in the src/Controller/Api folder. Therefore, this solution allows you to define this configuration only once.